# Robust String Split

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function:

```
function doSomething(arg) {
    var array = arg.split(',');
    // etc...
}
```

`arg` is populated using jQuery's `.data('myId')` function.

Often, `myId` contains a comma separated list of integers and the code works great.  However, if `myId` only contains a single integer, the code fails with the error

> Object doesn't support property or method 'split'

Is there a compact, robust method to create the array without including `if` statements to handle the boundary conditions of one integer or an empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two unrelated problems.

The first one is for case of empty string: Split will return a one-element array with an empty string. Just check for it and compensate.

```
var array;
if (arg == "") array = [];
```

If there is a single integer, I believe you are not getting a string from the `.data()`, but an actual integer; so first convert it into a string:

```
else array = String(arg).split(',');
```

Alternately, you could just avoid the jQuery magic, and access the attribute directly - all `data()` attributes are just attributes with `data-` prefixed.

Answer (score 2):

`attr` will return a string, while `data` will try to parse the value and return an object with the "correct" type.

```
foo.attr('data-myId');  //pass this instead
```

You can't get around identifying an empty string without an `if` though.  You either need to check for it, or for an array with a single empty string element.

Answer (score 1):

`.data` will try to guess the type of the value based on its contents, so it becomes a number.  You could use `.attr`, which always returns a string if it's available as an attribute.  Alternatively, cast to a string:

```
('' + arg).split(',')
//or
String(arg).split(',')
```

I'm actually not sure whether one is preferred or not.

Also note that `''.split(',')` returns `['']` or an array with an empty string element.  You can get around that with `.filter(function (elem) { return elem !== ''; })`

Another possible alternative is to use `dataset` on the element itself.